# how to keep a mac shell command script for exiting

Tags: macos, shell

I have a shell script that I put into a *.command file on mac os x, however it keeps exiting after the 2nd step and not doing the 3rd step which is to copy the file.  How can I keep the shell script from exiting after the build command and to continue to the copy step?

```
cd /Projects/my-app
ionic build android --release
cp /Projects/my-app/my-app-release.apk /Dropbox/my-app-release.apk
```

This is the output I get where it completes the 2nd build step but doesn't continue to the 3rd step

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 10 seconds
logout

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Do you mean `/Dropbox` or `~/Dropbox`?

Comment: You should probably also put a proper shebang line as the first line so you know what shell you are using, i.e. make the very first line `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @MarkSetchell the dropbox paths are fake placeholders for example only, and the shell is the default shell that mac os X comes with.

Comment: Please add a shebang, as I suggested earlier. Then try replacing the line `ionic build...` with `echo hello` and see if the the `cp` command gets executed then. If it does, your `ionic` command is at fault.